# row coloring is not complete

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Please see the rmarkdown file below.

When you run it the row with letter= b should be colored red all the way across but because the group is "" it does not color across. Any idea how to fix this? If I put "-" in the cell it will color all red but I need to have it blank.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r test}


library(kableExtra)

data = data.frame(letter = c("a","b")  , group=c("g",""))

kable(
      data, 
      format ="latex",
      caption = "",
      booktabs = T,
      longtable = T,
      escape = F,
      align = "c",
      linesep=""
      ) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = c(
      "striped",
        "repeat_header"
        ),
        font_size=7)%>%
   row_spec(2, bold = T,  background = "red")  
```
````

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to fill the blank cells with a non-breaking space `~`:

```
data = data.frame(letter = c("a","b")  , group=c("g","~"))
```